# Android Done button instead of Next

Tags: android, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with the keyboard. I have a `ListView` with edit texts, and when the keyboard opens for the first time the Done button is displayed instead of Next. The problem is that I need to use `adjustResize` in the *AndroidManifest.xml* and the list is moved up when the keyboard is displayed, so I think this is why the keyboard is not working properly.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 24):

Add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to the field where you need a done button on your keyboard.
Add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to the field where you need a next button.

Also, ime has many option buttons like go, send, search, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In your layout, just set the `XML` attributes `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for your EditText boxes in which you want next button to show and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` for the last one.

To gain focus for your `editText` just do like this :

```
your_editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
{
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) 
        {
            your_editText.requestfocus(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I already have tried to set "actionNext" ime option, and the Next button is displayed, but when I tap on it, the cursor goes only on the visible edit texts on the screen, the list is not scrolled.

Comment: I have tried your code, but the cursor remains in the edit text (it doesn't go to the next edit text). However, I tried to return false, but the behavior is like before, the cursor jumps off only to the visible edit texts :(